# Read multiple items from list box to query information from a database

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, oracle, listbox

Ok so what I'm trying to do is allow the users of my web form in asp.net to select multiple assets from a list box.  When they select these assets and press the select button it fires the following code which should run through the selected indices, query the DB for the description and asset tag's, and populate the Description and Asset tag boxes with those values.  Working through this I've been able to get it to read the values from the database and populate the fields but it would only populate the value from the first selected item and it would just insert the same value equal to the number of times equal to the number of items selected in the inbox.  I tried my current code to run through the indices a little better but it seems to be failing the If statement and I just can't figure out why.  Any help is appreciated, thanks everyone!

```
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To lstAssets.GetSelectedIndices.Count
        If lstAssets.Items(i).Selected = True Then

            Dim str2 As String = lstAssets.Items(i).Value.ToString

            Dim cs As New OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CSIWebUpd").ConnectionString)
            Dim ds As String = cs.DataSource
            Dim cn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection("user id=webupd;password=webupd;data source=" + ds)
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT description, tag FROM assets WHERE id = :id"
            Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(sql, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = str2
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.BindByName = True
            cn.Open()
            Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            dr.Read()

            desc = dr.GetString(0).ToString
            ass = dr.GetString(1).ToString

            If txtDescription.Text = Nothing Then
                txtDescription.Text = dr.GetString(0).ToString
            Else
                txtDescription.Text = txtDescription.Text + Chr(13) + Chr(10) + dr.GetString(0).ToString
            End If

            If txtAsset.Text = Nothing Then
                txtAsset.Text = dr.GetString(1).ToString
            Else
                txtAsset.Text = txtAsset.Text + Chr(13) + Chr(10) + dr.GetString(1).ToString
            End If

            cmd.Dispose()
            cn.Close()
        End If
    Next i
    UpdatePanel1.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional
    UpdatePanel1.Update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would work with the SelectedIndices values in this way

```
For Each i in lstAssets.GetSelectedIndices
```

Now i contains the index of the items selected not the offset of the GetSelectedIndices array

The [GetSelectedIndices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.getselectedindices%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an array where every element of the array is the index in the Items collection where you have an item selected.

An example could explain better:

Supposing the the items selected are 1, 5 6 (Count=3), your code set the value of i to  0,1,2 and then uses that value to lookup the ID in the items collection, but the following check on `lstAssets.Items(i).Selected` found just the item at index 1 as selected. Instead using the for each approach you get the values 1,5,6.

Comment: thank you very much for your help.  That makes perfect sense and I kinda figured the count was the issue but I couldn't figure out a better way to do it.  That single change snapped everything together.